# Select tag on mobile and laptop displays

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have the following div. It contains a panel heading where I am facing the issue. The panel body is getting displayed fine. So I gave the code only for panel heading.

```
<div class="panel panel-default" style="margin: 8px;margin-top: -10px;">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h5>Legislators By State</h5>
        <div class="search" style="float: right;margin-top: -29px;">
            <form class="form-inline">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select ng-model="state_select" ng-options="f.name for f in state_select | orderBy:'name'">
                        <option value="">ALL STATES</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

1)I want the `h5` tag to be displayed on the left and the select box on the right on both mobile and laptop displays. Currently it's working for laptop but not for mobiles.
2)In laptop displays the select should behave normally i.e. like a drop down to select items from. While in mobile I want that when a user clicks the options to be displayed like now a days we get the options scroll-able at the bottom of the screen. So that user can scroll through all the options and select one value.

I am new at responsive design thing so just trying to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Use, Bootstrap's Column classes.. here `col-xs-6` .... "xs" used for mobile devices and "6" is how many columns we want for that div from total 12 column grid.

```
<div class="panel panel-default" style="margin: 8px;margin-top: -10px;">
<div class="panel-heading">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <h5>Legislators By State</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="search">
        <form class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control" ng-model="state_select" ng-options="f.name for f in state_select | orderBy:'name'">
                    <option value="">ALL STATES</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: solution is a good start, bootstrap has some interesting classes you can try, for a full reference on this responsive classes go to: [Bootstrap Responsive Utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities).